# django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE because it has pending trigger events

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to change `accepted_answer` ForeignKey to a BooleanField and while migrating getting the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "forum_thread" because it has pending trigger events`. This is the `models.py` of before:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answer_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    accepted_answer = models.ForeignKey('forum.Post', null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error seems to happen when trying to update and change schema of the same table in one operation.

For example, after providing new default values when prompted by `makemigrations` when removing `null=True` from a field, this error seems to appear because Django is trying to change nullability while also updating the column.

Workarounds, depending on situation:

- Easiest is often adding a new field with the desired properties, then removing the old field (maybe after copying data over).
- If the error can be avoided by setting values for all fields that were needing a new default value (Django asking during the migration), try setting those values before making the migration/schema change.

In your specific case, adding a new field then removing the old is probably the way to go.

Comment: adding a new field, migrate and remove old is the easy solution. also, In my experience, if once you had this error, you better get a fresh database, and restart migrating.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Max Lemieux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801693/848811), if you try to change a field from nullable to non-nullable, this is impossible in the same database transaction, thus:

- you can split your operations into 2 migrations (not recommended if complex operations)
- you can wrap your migration's operations with these two statements to force PostgreSQL to check null constraint on save and not at the end of transaction

  ```py
  operations = [
      migrations.RunSQL('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE', reverse_sql='SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED'),
      ... # your other operations here
      migrations.RunSQL('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED', reverse_sql='SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE'),
  ]
  ```